# UWP and headers

Tags: azure, windows-10, win-universal-app, iot

I am building UWP application sending HTTP(s) requests to remote server and I have problem adding HTTP headers "Content-Type". I have tried to use method HttpRequestMessage.Headers.Add, ended with exception. Then HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation, not doing anything. Any idea/hint what to do, please?

Comment: Please edit your question to add your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using this code:

```
using (var hc = new HttpClient()) {
    var content = new StringContent(..., Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    using (var response = await hc.PostAsync(..., content)) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Or this one:

```
using (var hc = new HttpClient()) {
    var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    content.Add(new FileContent(..., "text/xml", ...));
    using (var response = await hc.PostAsync(..., content)) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly,

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("<type>"));
```

ought to do the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

The content type header is added when you set the content of your request. You cannot alter the header directly.

You should have a look at the HttpXXXContent classes of the [Windows.Web.Http](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.aspx) namespace.

For example, if you are sending your content as string, you can use the [HttpStringContent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn279669.aspx) as:

```
var content = new HttpStringContent("my content string", Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8, "text/xml");
var response = await m_client.PostAsync(m_serverUri, content;
```

You can also use [HttpFormUrlEncodedContent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.httpformurlencodedcontent.aspx), [HttpBufferContent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.httpbuffercontent.aspx)...